# How can I create and initialize a schema for a embedded MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, embedded, perl

I want to create an embedded MySQL database for running tests, but I'm not sure how to do it.

- How do I initialize the database?
- How do I run my create table statements?

I'm using Perl, so it needs to be done with a language and not a couple of commands.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the functions from the C/C++ API

- **mysql_library_init()** : Should be called before any other MySQL function is called, preferably early in the main() function.
- **mysql_library_end()** : Should be called before your program exits.
- **mysql_thread_init()** : Should be called in each thread you create that accesses MySQL.
- **mysql_thread_end()** : Should be called before calling pthread_exit()

*Personally, I have searched high and low for the Perl equivalent of these C/C++ API calls that would open an embedded MySQL Server. Apparently, none exists for the Perl API.*

Here is an [**excerpt from dev.mysql.com**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/libmysqld.html) that verifies this:

> The embedded MySQL server library
>   makes it possible to run a
>   full-featured MySQL server inside a
>   client application. The main benefits
>   are increased speed and more simple
>   management for embedded applications.
>
> The embedded server library is based
>   on the client/server version of MySQL,
>   which is written in C/C++.
>   Consequently, the embedded server also
>   is written in C/C++. **There is no
>   embedded server available in other
>   languages**.

You may have to manually trigger the start of mysql yourself with something like this:

```
@args = {"/sbin/service","mysql","status"};
$rc = 0xFFFF & system(@args);
if ( $rc != 0 ) {
    @args = {"/sbin/service","mysql","start"};
    system(@args) == 0 or die "mysql start failed : $?";
}
```

Comment: yeah I've only found brief reference to embedded mysql in [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#Class_Methods)